# Customizing "Algorithmic" or generating output of the same style

Tags: algorithms

The algorithmic sample code that I am using is something like this:

```
‎\begin{algorithm}[h]‎  
\caption{Caption Here‎.} \label{alg:Name}  ‎‎   
\begin{algorithmic}[1]‎  
‎\REQUIRE‎  
‎\ENSURE‎  
  ‎\STATE‎  
  ‎\STATE‎  
  ‎\STATE‎     
‎\end{algorithmic}     ‎
‎\end{algorithm}‎
```

> How can I customize the algorithmic output? for example, when I just entered the \REQUIRE it give me the Setup keyword. BTW, I don't want the numbering along each line, may be I just should not use this package at all :D.

I tried to bypass using such package with some \hrule and \rule defined above and below the text like this:

```
\rule{\textwidth}{‎2‎pt}  
Some text goes here for cation of the algorithm  
\rule{\textwidth}{‎2‎pt}
```

But the text and everything in between goes to the outside of page margin. I just used the code

```
\vspace{2pt}‎‎‎‎‎‎  
\hrule‎  
‎\vspace{2pt}
```

‎‎‎‎‎
instead of the second `\rule` but still not satisfied with the output, esp. the thickness of the `\hrule`.

[image]

Please ignore the Persian writings, I want the headline of my algorithm like that without using algorithmic, or using algorithmic package and customized texts for '\ENSURE' and '\REQUIRE'.

> **Edit (New Question)**: How can I have the same output using ordinary lines? In other words, how can I define the thickness of two consecutive lines such that the text in-between does not fall outside of the page margin?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I guess you want to use rules in some way that is similar in appearance to `algorithmic` but vastly different in function. You should describe your end goal.

Comment: The first question is answered, but it seems that it could be easier to get the same output if any body can answer the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to the second question can be found at:
[latex-Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7769)

I copy and paste the answer:

```
    \documentclass{article}
      \newenvironment{question}{\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}\begin{list}{*}{}\item}{\end{list}}

      \newenvironment{questions}{}{\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}}

\begin{document}
Hello world
  \begin{questions}
     \begin{question}Item one\end{question}
     \begin{question}Item two\end{question}
     \begin{question}Item three\end{question}
  \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The (redefinable) definitions of the algorithms package are listed on p. 13 of the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf).
Example:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
```

If you want to change the effects of `\REQUIRE` to, say, *Whatever:* (typeset in italic), add the following to the preamble of your document:

```
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textit{Whatever:}}
```